# Python how to save datetime.strptime in datetime.time format

Tags: python, datetime

So I was trying to make a simple code using datetime and came across an error.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
x = True
b = datetime.strptime("06:10", "%H:%M")
while x == True:
    a = datetime.now().time()
    print(a)
    if a > b:
        x = False
time.sleep(0.945)
```

As a result I get

```
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.time() > datetime.datetime()
```

So I was wondering if it's possible to save a datetime.strptime in the datetime.time() format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should compare them before calling striptime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to compare a `datetime` and `time` object, which Python won't let you compare.

If you do `datetime.strptime()` you get an object which holds a date and time (called `datetime`). But because you do not also parse the date it defaults to 01-01-1900. Now `datetime.now()` also gets you a `datetime` object but with the current date. So directly comparing `datetime.now()` and `b` won't work because the dates are different.

Now you already use the current time only by doing `datetime.now().time()`, so you also need to apply that to `b` by doing `b = b.time()` somewhere before the comparison.

Comment: The `b` object has the date `1900-01-01`, they really want to compare *times* only. There is no point in comparing the full `datetime` instances.

Comment: Darn, I thought it would use the current date. I expanded/rewrote my answer to explain that directly comparing them won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `.time()` of both `a` and `b` as:

```
if a > b.time():  # if you want to compare only time
```

*and not the `datetime` objects. Reason at the end of the answer.*

[`datetime.now().time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) is of `datetime.time` type:

```
>>> type(datetime.now().time())
<type 'datetime.time'>
```

whereas, [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) are of `datetime.datetime` type:

```
>>> type(datetime.strptime("06:10", "%H:%M"))
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> type(datetime.now())
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

---

Edit based on comment from  *[Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)*.

On creating `datetime` object like `datetime.strptime("06:10", "%H:%M")` date will be set as `1900-01-01`. And definitely I dont't think you want to compare with that. You may check the date as:

```
>>> d = datetime.strptime("06:10", "%H:%M")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 10)
```

Comment: The `b` object has the date `1900-01-01`, they really want to compare *times* only. There is no point in comparing the full `datetime` instances.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, you have the point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use 'datetime.now()' insted of 'datetime.now().time()'

Comment: The `b` object models the date `1900-01-01` (as well as a time comporent). What use is there in comparing today to that?

Comment: type(b)
datetime.datetime



type(datetime.now())

Comment: type(b) is datetime.datetime and type(datetime.now()) also datetime.datetime

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean that the *value* of that `datetime` object is of any use. `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 10, 0)` is *always* going to be smaller than a timestamp with a 2016 date, the exact time doesn't matter.